# How to Use RabbitMq in Magento2 CE

Tags: magento2, database, cron, queue, rabbit-mq

I have follow this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html) to  knows about **RabbitMq** is used in **Magento2EE**. for Instead of **Mysql+cron** Process in **Magento2CE**.

I annualized about some drawbacks while using **Mysql+Cron in Magento 2 CE**. follow this [link](http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-use-rabbitmq-queue-in-extensions-for-magento-2-0-ee.html)

> Disadvantages if compared to real queue-solutions: first off, cron is running as a cycle so you are not able to immediately react on adding of a record into the queue. Secondly, using such a scheme makes it quite difficult to parallel a queue. Magento 2.0 EE gives you the possibility to use queues not only on the basis of Mysql+cron, but also on the basis of RabbitMq.

I need to overcome these drawback, I saw this statement magento2 devdocs [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html)

> RabbitMQ must be installed and configured after Magento Community Edition and before Magento Enterprise Edition.

so I install and integrate rabbitmq in magento2 CE. follow this [install rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html) and [Integrate to magento 2CE](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) after follow this [guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) to working samples to use Rabbitmq.

Next I Have configured **rabbitmq** to **magento2CE**

add my **env.php** like this:

```
   'queue' => [
            'amqp' => [
                'host' => 'hostip',
                'port' => '5672',
                'user' => 'user1',
                'password' => 'userpass',
                'virtualhost' => '/',
                'ssl' => ''
            ]
        ]
```

Next I create a queue.xml in custom module:

Vendor/Module/etc/queue.xml:

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/queue.xsd">
        <publisher name="test-publisher-1" connection="rabbitmq" exchange="magento"/>
        <topic name="customer.created" schema="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface" publisher="test-publisher-1"/>
        <consumer name="customerCreatedListener" queue="test-queue-1" connection="rabbitmq" class="vendor\RabbitMq\Block\Testing" method="processMessage"/>
        <bind queue="test-queue-1" exchange="magento" topic="customer.created" />
    </config>
```

**Consumer Class:**

vendor/Module/Block/Testing:

```
    <?php
      namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

    require_once  '/var/www/public/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

    class Testing //extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {


      public function processMessage($argv)
      {
              $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('hostip', 5672, 'user1', 'userpass');
              $channel = $connection->channel();

              $channel->exchange_declare('magento', 'topic', false, false, false);

              list($queue_name, ,) = $channel->queue_declare("test-queue-1", false, false, true, false);

              $binding_keys = array_slice($argv, 0);
              if( empty($binding_keys )) {
                  file_put_contents('php://stderr', "Usage: $argv[0] [binding_key]\n");
                  exit(1);
              }

              foreach($binding_keys as $binding_key) {
                  $channel->queue_bind($queue_name, 'magento', $binding_key);
              }

              echo ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

              $callback = function($msg){
                  echo ' [x] ',$msg->delivery_info['routing_key'], ':', $msg->body, "\n";
              };

              $channel->basic_consume($queue_name, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

              while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
                  $channel->wait();
              }

              $channel->close();
              $connection->close();

      }

    }

    $test = new Testing();
    $arr =array("customer.*");
    $test->processMessage($arr);
```

I have listen **customerCreatedListener**, after Configured , I try to create one new customer, But NO queue added in rabbit mq,

Reference:

[image]

Suggest Me

1. Can we use Rabbitmq in magento2 CE?
2. If use  **Rabbitmq** in magento2 CE, what I miss in my Configuration.
3. How to use **Rabbitmq** instead of **Mysql+Cron** in Magento2 CE

Answer (score 3):

Integration with Rabbitmq is EE only functionality.

But you can use it in CE version if use external library and develop infrastructure by self.

Also, you can create separate group for cron task and write code in style like

```
$startTime = microtime();
while( microtime(1) - $startTume > 60 * 1000) {
   // process messages
   usleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Magento2 module [enqueue/magento2-enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/magento2-enqueue) that provides support for RabbitMQ broker and many others.

The module provides easy to use CLI commands, backend UI section, setup queues and exchanges on broker side for you.

Supports pub\sub and one to one messaging with an ability to get a reply.